# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: database is locked: retrycount exceeded

Tags: android, sqlite, browser

I am trying to read browser history programmatically. Code is works fine but some time code gives "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: database is locked: retrycount exceeded". In my app this code accessed from multiple Threads, so now I have changed that method as `synchronized` which will read browser history from background. Now in my app this method will accessed only one by one because this method is `synchronized`.

Here is my code:

```
String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL,       Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.VISITS };

mCur = context.getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, proj, null, null, null);

if(mCur != null)
{
// Processing on cursor
}
```

But I want to know when Browser database will accessed by any other app and at the same time my app going to access the Browser database, then this exception will come. If Yes then how can I handle this case to avoid this exception.

Comment: please put your code...

Comment: are you close your cursor.

Comment: surround with try...catch() block.

Comment: @HarshitRathi Yes cursor will closed after all processing.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia Code already in try...catch() block. But I think this is not a solution.